# Remove index.php in permalink structure on IIS server

Tags: permalinks

In permalinks(dashboard) section index.php added.
e.g.

Current Post Name: http://zakatchicago.com/index.php/sample-post/
Expected Post Name: http://zakatchicago.com/sample-post/

How can i remove index.php?

**Note: I am using windows server**

Answer (score 1):

As of WP 5.9 (but I am sure way back years and versions) there is no need to add web.config manually.

*In case* **IIS rewrite module is installed (whichi is a prerequisite)** when you modify Settings/Permalink, WP automatically emits web.config into the root of  your site.

It even writes to the GUI a warning message, to revoke write access from web.config.

**If IIS rewrite module is not installed**, all of this above is not possible, neither manually, so WP will include the `/index.php/` fragment in the path. If you overwrite this setting with a custom permalink setting, then the links will adopt (so will not contain the `/index.php/` fragment, but because of lack of rewrite facility IIS will give `404`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation here: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/enabling-pretty-permalinks-in-wordpress

I assume you have already selected `Post Name` in your permalink structure:

Then include this code in `web.config`

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
    <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
    </rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Already I putted in root web.config file containing above code .But not any change.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12106064/remove-index-php-from-wordpress-urls-in-iis7 - you also need to set the permalink structure found in the accepted answer at this link.

Comment: @DerreckDean Thanks, I think I have already mentioned it before the code.